# Golf me a polygonal loader

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, animation

[Codidact post](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/280092), [CGCC Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20491/80214), [Codidact Sandbox](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/279245)

Given three positive integers as input, animate an ascii-art polygonal loading symbol on the screen.

### Intro

You will be given three inputs, \$n\$, \$l\$, and \$d\$...

\$n\$ (one of \$3\$, \$4\$, \$6\$, or \$8\$), is the number of sides of a polygon:

```
                           * * *
                          *     *
                * * *    *       *
               *     *   *       *
  *    * * *  *       *  *       *
 * *   *   *   *     *    *     *
* * *  * * *    * * *      * * *
```

\$l\$ is the side length to use. (The above all use \$l = 3\$, the minimum possible value).

You may use any printable ASCII character other than space instead of `*`.

\$d\$ is the load length and is less than the perimeter.

The task is to create a loading animation as follows:

1. Make the first frame of the animation by starting at any one of the topmost corners and drawing the perimeter until its length is \$d\$.
2. Make the next frame by shifting this partial perimeter by 1 clockwise.
3. Repeat step 2 ad-infinitum.

For example, \$n=3,l=3,d=4\$ would result in the following steps:

```
  *                          *       *        *
   *  ->    *  ->  *    ->  *   ->  * *  ->  * *  -> . . .
  * *    * * *    * * *    * *     *            *
```

### Example

Here is a solution made by [Hakerh400](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/280096#answer-280096): [Try It Online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/cg/280092/)

### Further details(important):

- You are guaranteed that \$n∊(3,4,6,8)\$
- You are guaranteed that \$l≥3.\$
  You are guaranteed that \$d<(l-1)×n.\$
- There must be a delay of at least 0.1 s between each step. You can have a delay of up to 10 seconds.
- Your language is allowed to output a list of steps infinitely if and only if it cannot clear the screen or do something similar.
- If so, there must be at least 2 newlines between each step.
- This is not [graphical-output](/questions/tagged/graphical-output).

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Could you specify that \$n\$ is the number of sides of the polygon, rather than an index, earlier in the question?

Comment: Also for the example, it might be worth using a larger side length to make it clearer.

Comment: @pxeger clarified that part.

Comment: @pxeger I'll add in a larger side length example sometime, sure.

Comment: must we use `*`?

Comment: @pxeger clarified that as well.

Comment: You wrote "other than space", so you clarified for the empty character but not for "*" actually

Comment: Could you show what the output looks like for more examples?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Edited it in.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>353</s> 318 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,l,d,o=0)=>{w=[...{3:'330231',4:'42240220',6:'423313021131',8:'4233231302112131'}[n]]
a=Array(3*l).fill().map(_=>Array(4*l).fill` `)
x=n==4?0:l,y=0
for(i=0;i<d+o;++i){a[y][x]=i>=o?'*':' '
j=~~(i/(l-1))%n*2
x+=w[j]-2
y+=w[j+1]-2}(c=console).clear()
c.log(a.join`
`.replace(/,/g,''))
setTimeout(_=>f(n,l,d,o+1),100)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDLbsIwFET3/go2lX2JMX5EFQq9oP5Dd1HUWCFBjkyMkhSIEPx6SkrZzZyzGU1tT7YrWnfsF6fVOFbIGu75jgeUgJvrGVMhxNUk1BipjaI8TmisdSy1lpS/T8UY9XBKTXb1BPof6Qne0ibLiMXPtrUDM3MPonLeMxAHe2TfuHmK@CXyWQ7kgg1ivJWJ5wNKUoWWOZRr97GLwjqKHFxtOmTpJUO3wbClc5rQGSU13u/MLZlfKIC3Zq7JJcJzWmcLTYa/FKlHvrECi9B0wZcgCl/algEphA97ZkUdXJOTXLTl0duiZEu@3HNKAUhX9l/uUIaffppdva6KFHAlJdzGihlueAzjLw)

On the tio.run it displays all output instantly, but in the browser console it animates as it should.

```js
f=(n,l,d,o=0)=>{w=[...{3:'330231',4:'42240220',6:'423313021131',8:'4233231302112131'}[n]]
a=Array(3*l).fill().map(_=>Array(4*l).fill` `)
x=n==4?0:l,y=0
for(i=0;i<d+o;++i){a[y][x]=i>=o?'*':' '
j=~~(i/(l-1))%n*2
x+=w[j]-2
y+=w[j+1]-2}(c=console).clear()
c.log(a.join`
`.replace(/,/g,''))
setTimeout(_=>f(n,l,d,o+1),100)}
f(3,3,4)
```

Comment: Does it work as a Stack Snippet?

Comment: @Neil, Yes, it works. Added to answer.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES8), 265 bytes

```javascript
(n,l,d)=>setInterval(_=>(g=i=>i<q?g(i+1,(m[y-=634%~(D+=i%l?0:+("02112122230"[(n*12^i/l)%43%29]||1))-2>>1]=m[y]||[...''.padEnd(l*4)])[x-=D<4?D-1:5-D]=(i+j)%q<d?0:" "):C.log(m.reverse().map(r=>r.join``).join`
`))(y=D=!++j,(C=console).clear(x=l*3,m=[])),j=100,q=n*--l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3RaoMwFEDf9xWbIL1Xk8xEO6j02oe6h32DuFVqKpEY21hKC2W/7oQ9Hc7LOX1za6ajN@crd2Or5xPN4JhlLVIx6euXu2p/ayz8UAEdGSrM9rLrwMSSwVA9OH2kWfgLZUwmtLskjyFIlJRKKqXSJKjARVJ9m3eLYZaGalM/nxKRq6KQNS2BxSshxGolzk376VqwUYY1VndO5TbblVzma17WtBx7DC/bdnkErwHme2HHDgbh9U37SQOKoTmDp8KLfjTucMB/vhwQ4UElvcVxz2BPx9FNo9UojlY3Hu5ko5QNVNWIrCeZJOxCLuLc4nyClK3ZBuc/)

#### Snippet

```js
f=

(n,l,d)=>setInterval(_=>(g=i=>i<q?g(i+1,(m[y-=634%~(D+=i%l?0:+("02112122230"[(n*12^i/l)%43%29]||1))-2>>1]=m[y]||[...''.padEnd(l*4)])[x-=D<4?D-1:5-D]=(i+j)%q<d?0:" "):C.log(m.reverse().map(r=>r.join``).join`
`))(y=D=!++j,(C=console).clear(x=l*3,m=[])),j=100,q=n*--l)

console.log = s => o.innerHTML = s; f(3, 5, 9)
```

```html
<pre id="o"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≔⁰εＲＷφ¹«≦⊖εＦ§⪪”)″‴Byε=μχ？⟦⌕r”8θＦ⊖η«≦⊕ε✳Ｉκ⁺§ *‹﹪ε×⊖ηθζ× №04κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Ra4MwFIWf9VeEPN0MB9pZFfZU2hdhHWUb7Nnp7QyLiU3iGB397e7WjiJ9CeckOec7dVvZ2lRqHEvdD/556D7QwkE8hnPf3vgj@ZVz8lNDHDEk94J7i659b6VCSOgyEew3DLZV//9vg7XFDrXH5pII9sYyWPlSN/gDr72SHni@TB@SuCjyjMSCVJ4mRZYu4oJHjBdcROwgBJuis0YaOOFmvFLf8oKdldrDRlqsvTQa1pXz8CWoc6cGd53C2R3BntA52JpmUAYwYm@yQ3eDnLZE7Hg@Lu@cUXJtBsLwOCVN7eLMPoWncczCZZiP99/qDw) Link is to verbose version of code with 100× speed-up (`φ` replaced with `χ`) so that you can get results in a reasonable amount of time; each frame is separated by `␛ [2J␛ [0;0H`. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input `n`, `l` and `d` as numbers.

```
≔⁰ε
```

Keep track of how many frames have passed and which step we are on the current frame.

```
ＲＷφ¹«
```

Every second, run the rest of the code and refresh the screen.

```
≦⊖ε
```

Decrement the frame/step counter, so that each frame starts a step later than the previous.

```
Ｆ§⪪”)″‴Byε=μχ？⟦⌕r”8θ
```

Look up the direction vectors for the appropriate shape in a compressed string and loop over them.

```
Ｆ⊖η«
```

Loop over the length of each side.

```
≦⊕ε
```

Increment the frame/step counter.

```
✳Ｉκ⁺§ *‹﹪ε×⊖ηθζ× №04κ
```

Print a `*` if the frame/step counter is within the input length, plus a further space for a horizontal movement.